# Help and Improvement - audits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, help-improvement

I think the **Help and Improvement** queue is the only review queue that does not undertake audits. Who is responsible for peer reviewers then?

I mean, anyone could just change one character and then just click next... What can be done about this?

Comment: Such superficial edits, when lots more is neccessary, often happen.

Comment: As far as I can tell, some seem to go through more than one reviewers H&I queue, so several eyes check the edits. I see edits made shortly before by someone else clearly doing H&I. Sometimes I further edit, sometimes there is nothing left to do.

Comment: It's difficult to imagine an audit system that would fit into the current scheme, which is, I imagine, why there are presently no audits. I've tossed around a few ideas, but nothing particularly great has occurred to me yet. If you can think of some solid approach, by all means suggest it!